# Unity3d getting BoxCollider2D.size.x value

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, size, 2d

I'm making a 2d game in a Unity3d, and I need to get `BoxCollider2D` `size.x` value. As documentations says, I can get the size of a box just with `size = BoxCollider2D.size.x`, But it does not work! Console says `An object reference is required to access non-static member 'UnityEngine.BoxCollider2D.size'`. I've tried to change capital letters to small, I've tried to use GetComponent method, I've tried to create component variable and define it in inspector. All of that does not work. Please, help me!

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to the `GameObject` or its `Collider` which contains the `BoxCollider2D`. Once you have the reference then by default you have access to the `BoxCollider2D`.

```
BoxCollider2D col = gameObject.collider2D as BoxCollider2D;
int x = col.size.x;
```

You could use `GetComponent()`, but that is overkill once you have the required `GameObject`, which the answer by ContingencyCoder failed to mention.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to a BoxCollider2D component. e.g.

`var size = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size.x;`

Comment: This answer only works as long as the script is attached to the `GameObject` which contains the `BoxCollider2D`.